# Specify a network interface with nodejs net.Socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

For some reasons, i want to code a proxy server that route its requests through its wifi interface instead of ethernet (which is the default route on the OS level). I know i could do that by fiddling with os routes but i would prefer to do it directly in nodeJS.

I have read that you actually can choose the network interface a socket will use with the localAddress option but it doesn't seem to work for me :(

I tried the following:

```
const proxy_socket = net.Socket();
proxy_socket.connect(
   {port: target.port, host: target.hostname, localAddress: '192.168.43.159'},
   function() {
        logger.info('connect to %s, port %d', target.hostname, target.port);
    }
);
```

But i only get ETIMEDOUT errors.

Does anyone has a clue on how to achieve what i want ? Is it even possible using node only ?

Comment: If the remote server you wish to connect to speaks HTTP(S), you could try using cURL to see if you can actually reach it over the WiFi interface: `curl --interface 192.168.43.159 http://HOST:PORT/`

Comment: i tried curl --interface and i get a timeout error too when using the wifi interface. When i am using the ethernet interface (even with --interface), it works like expected...

Comment: Okay so that would explain why your Node code is timing out as well :)

Comment: indeed :p But it doesn't give me a solution...

Comment: I understand, but it has become a networking problem, not a programming problem. So perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) is a more appropriate SE site for this particular problem.

Comment: You're right. I opened another thread regarding the curl issue here: http://superuser.com/questions/1148582/specify-a-network-interface-with-curl